# Integrate MSAL / AAD auth into existing server-client JWT auth

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

We have an existing API with role based authentication using JWTs and looking to integrate Azure AD auth as an alternative to our current username + password based auth flow.

The current flow is best described with the following picture

[image: current auth flow]

Since the JWT contains all the users roles/permissions etc. we would like to continue using the JWT mechanism and just want to use the AAD login as an alternative to the username + password login that checks for the credentials in our own database. Eventually we could remove all credentials from our DB (if all users would use AAD auth).

The following flow is desired:

[image: desired aad flow]

Is this generally a reasonable approach? Is this flow one example for the OAuth 2.0 auth code flow?

Answer (score 1):

Approach is pretty fine. Please take a look to [Tutorial: Sign in users and call the Microsoft Graph API in an Electron desktop app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-nodejs-desktop). Replace the calls and scopes to the Microsoft Graph API with your own.

Also, take a look to [Add app roles to your application and receive them in the token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps).